# How to Make multiple SQL queries using php for dynamically inserted html elements

Tags: javascript, php, oracle

I made a html file which takes some fixed user input and some Dynamic  user inputs.
Following user inputs are  Dynamically inserted by JavaScript:

Image given below:

[image]

Here is the HTML source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         table, th, td {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         }
      </style>
      <script>
         function addMore() {
             var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
             var row = table.insertRow(-1);
             var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
             var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
         
         var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[1].cells;
            
             cell1.innerHTML =  x[0].innerHTML;
             cell2.innerHTML = x[1].innerHTML;
         }
         
         
         function removeLast() {
             document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
         }
         
         function removeRowNo() {
         var index = document.getElementById('value').value
             document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(index);
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form  action="payroll.php" method="post">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Month:  
               </td>
               <td>
                  <select name="SALMT" id="month" onchange="" size="1">
                     <option value="" disabled selected>Month</option>
                     <option value="1">January</option>
                     <option value="2">February</option>
                     <option value="3">March</option>
                     <option value="4">April</option>
                     <option value="5">May</option>
                     <option value="6">June</option>
                     <option value="7">July</option>
                     <option value="8">August</option>
                     <option value="9">September</option>
                     <option value="10">October</option>
                     <option value="11">November</option>
                     <option value="12">December</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td>
                  Year:
               </td>
               <td> <input type="text" name="SALYR">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Employee ID:
               </td>
               <td> <input type="text" name="EMPID">
               </td>
               <td>
                  Name: 
               </td>
               <td><input type="text" name="NM">  
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Department Code:
               </td>
               <td> <input type="text" name="DPTID">
               </td>
               <td>
                  Designation: 
               </td>
               <td><input type="text" name="DSG"> 
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
               <th>Expenses</th>
               <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <select id="mySelect" name="DESCR" >
                     <option  disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
                     <option value="BASIC PAY">BASIC PAY</option>
                     <option  value="HOUSE RENT">HOUSE RENT</option>
                     <option  value="GAS BILL">GAS BILL</option>
                     <option  value="TELEPHONE BILL">TELEPHONE BILL</option>
                     <option  value="HEALTH INSURANCE">HEALTH INSURANCE</option>
                     <option  value="CLUB">CLUB</option>
                     <option  value="MEDICINE">MEDICINE</option>
                     <option  value="BANK LOAN">BANK LOAN</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td> <input type="text" name="ALAMT"></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      <br>
      <button onclick="addMore()">Add More</button>
      <button onclick="removeLast()">Remove Last Row</button>
      <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="value" id='value'>
      <button onclick="removeRowNo()">Remove By Row No.</button>   
   </body>
</html>
```

I also made a php file which takes these inputs from html and insert them to Oracle Database correctly.
But the problem arise, when i try to insert these Dynamic  user inputs into Oracle Database, because Database TABLE columns are fixed.i think, if i some how make equal number of insert queries for a Number
of Dynamic  user inputs then, exactly  that number of tuple/row can be inserted.But,to do so i need to identify each 
Dynamic  user inputs and total number of Dynamic  user inputs to generate multiple queries using php loops.I don't how to do this.Please suggest me how can i do this or more better alternatives to do it.

Here is the PHP source code:

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('usr', '123', 'localhost/xe');

if (!$conn)
    {
    trigger_error("Could not connect to database", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Connection established";
    }

insertTable($conn); //This to insert date into table each time.
displayTable($conn);

function insertTable($conn)
    {
    $year = $_POST["SALYR"];
    $month = $_POST["SALMT"];
    $empID = $_POST["EMPID"];
    $dptCode = $_POST["DPTID"];
    $salHD = 'A9';
    $description = $_POST["DESCR"];
    $amount = $_POST["ALAMT"];
    $optID = 111;
    $trDate = date("Y/m/d", strtotime(date("Y/m/d")));
    $query = "INSERT INTO PAYROLLFILE VALUES (:bind1, :bind2, :bind3, :bind4, :bind5, :bind6, :bind7, :bind8, to_date(:bind9 ,'YY/mm/dd'))";
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind1", $year);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind2", $month);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind3", $empID);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind4", $dptCode);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind5", $salHD);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind6", $description);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind7", $amount);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind8", $optID);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bind9", $trDate);
    $r = oci_execute($stid);
    }

function displayTable($conn)
    {
    $query = 'select * from PAYROLLFILE';
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $r = oci_execute($stid);

    // Fetch each row in an associative array
    print '<table border="1" style=" border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;">';
    echo "<tr>";
    $ncols = oci_num_fields($stid);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++)
        {
        $column_name = oci_field_name($stid, $i);
        echo "<th>$column_name</th>";
        }

    echo "</tr>\n";
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS + OCI_ASSOC))
        {
        print '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $item)
            {
            print '<td>' . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : '&nbsp') . '</td>';
            }

        print '</tr>';
        }

    print '</table>';
    }

?>
```

Here is the Oracle 11g Table structure:
Image given below:
[image]

please let me know for any further information.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make those two fields array, add `[]` to end of those names

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <select id="mySelect" name="DESCR[]" >
      <option  disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
      <option value="BASIC PAY">BASIC PAY</option>
      <option  value="HOUSE RENT">HOUSE RENT</option>
      <option  value="GAS BILL">GAS BILL</option>
      <option  value="TELEPHONE BILL">TELEPHONE BILL</option>
      <option  value="HEALTH INSURANCE">HEALTH INSURANCE</option>
      <option  value="CLUB">CLUB</option>
      <option  value="MEDICINE">MEDICINE</option>
      <option  value="BANK LOAN">BANK LOAN</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td> <input type="text" name="ALAMT[]"></td>
</tr>
```

and loop through them in PHP code

```
$description = $_POST["DESCR"];
$amount = $_POST["ALAMT"];
for( $i = 0; $i < count($description); $i++) {
 // use $description[$i] and $amount[$i]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help.But this same select tags will appear in all dynamically insert html input.In that case how can i retrieve values from each of them.Thanks

Comment: @user5005768 you want change values for each select tag?

Comment: Thanks @Farnabaz. Now i got your idea. simple and clear.thanks